# Chained promises in Angular

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a list of records I want to process in sequence. A "root" promise needs to be passed back to be added as part of another parent chain.

```
processCategories = function(categories) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    // Process each category in sequence
    angular.forEach(categories, function (data, classIndex) {
        promise = promise.then(doSomethingAndReturnAPromise(categories, data, classIndex));

        if (classIndex === categories.length - 1) {
            // Last category has been reached, resolve this unit of work
            promise.then(function() {
                deferred.resolve(categories);
            });
        }
    });

    // Pass the root promise back to the chain
    return promise;
}

doSomethingAndReturnAPromise = function(categories, data, index) {
    console.log('item : ' + index + ' = started');
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    executeAnAsynchronousCall(function () {
            console.log('item : ' + index + ' = done');
            deferred.resolve(categories);

    }, function(status, text) {
            console.log('item : ' + index + ' = error');
            // Handle error here

    }, data);

    console.log('item : ' + index + ' = returned');
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I'm getting some errors from my asynchronous call because the executions are occurring at the same time (and not sequentially). I added the logging above and observed the following:

```
2014-08-08 11:38:02.702 item : 1 = started
2014-08-08 11:38:02.702 item : 1 = returned
2014-08-08 11:38:02.702 item : 2 = started
2014-08-08 11:38:02.703 item : 2 = returned
2014-08-08 11:38:02.703 item : 3 = started
2014-08-08 11:38:02.704 item : 3 = returned
2014-08-08 11:38:02.704 item : 4 = started
2014-08-08 11:38:02.705 item : 4 = returned
2014-08-08 11:38:02.705 item : 5 = started
2014-08-08 11:38:02.706 item : 5 = returned
2014-08-08 11:38:02.707 item : 6 = started
2014-08-08 11:38:02.707 item : 6 = returned
2014-08-08 11:38:02.708 item : 7 = started
2014-08-08 11:38:02.709 item : 7 = returned
2014-08-08 11:38:02.709 item : 8 = started
2014-08-08 11:38:02.710 item : 8 = returned

2014-08-08 11:38:02.716 item : 2 = error
2014-08-08 11:38:02.718 item : 3 = error
2014-08-08 11:38:02.719 item : 4 = error
2014-08-08 11:38:02.720 item : 5 = error
2014-08-08 11:38:02.722 item : 1 = done // (This has finished, the server is now expecting #2)
2014-08-08 11:38:02.723 item : 6 = error
2014-08-08 11:38:02.735 item : 8 = error
2014-08-08 11:38:02.754 item : 7 = error
```

I was expecting the `.then` to ensure the promises are run in sequence, but each time I run the code it appears they are all being fired at once.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: In `processCategories ` you are expecting to resolve a Deferred in the handler of a `.then()` chained to a promise derived from that same Deferred. Think about it - the resolve statement is dependent on the Deferred being resolved, thus it will never be reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second line is invoking the function rather than scheduling it to be invoked later

Change:

```
promise = promise.then(doSomethingAndReturnAPromise(categories, data, classIndex));
```

To:

```
promise = promise.then(doSomethingAndReturnAPromise.bind(this,categories, data, index));
```

Or a full blown anonymous function:

```
promise = promise.then(function(){
    return doSomethingAndReturnAPromise(categories, data, classIndex));
});
```

As a side note, if you need the promise to resolve with the categories, it would be simpler to change the return value directly rather than put that check in the forEach.

```
processCategories = function(categories) {
    return categories.reduce(function (prev, data, index) {
            return prev.then(function(){
                return doSomethingAndReturnAPromise(categories, data, index));
            });
    }, $q.when()).then(function(){
        return categories;
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This promise chaining can be easy to get lost in! That reduce/when approach looks useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Change `processCategories()` to something like this:

```
processCategories = function(categories) {
    var promise, deferred;

    // Process each category in sequence
    angular.forEach(categories, function (data, classIndex) {
      if(promise) {
        promise = promise.then(function() {
           return doSomethingAndReturnAPromise(categories, data, classIndex);
        });
      } else
        promise = doSomethingAndReturnAPromise(categories, data, classIndex);
    });

    if(promise) {
      promise.then(function() {
        return categories;
      });
    } else {
      deferred = $q.defer();
      promise = deferred.promise;
      deferred.resolve(categories);
    }


    // Pass the last promise
    return promise;
}
```