# How to wait for something that might already have happened in the past?

Tags: angularjs, promise

We have an application that is accessing an API using SignalR. Upon startup/loading of the page there are two things that will happen asyncronously

1. A SignalR connection is started. This will take a varying ammount
   of time before being finished (or perhaps not at all if the API
   server is not available).
2. Rendering of html template code containing
   some directive will trigger a call to `Login` for the API.

If the SignalR connection is finished before the `Login` call is done then there is no problems. But if the API is called first, we need to postpone invoking the function until the SignalR connection is ready.

The way I have solved this is to have in the service containing SignalR logic:

```
return {
    init: init,
    login: function (username, password) {
        waitForSignalRToHaveStarted().then(function () {
            $q.when(self.proxy.invoke('Login', username, password));
        });
    },
...
```

with the following in the main part of the service:

```
function init() {
    self.connection.start().done(function () {
        notifyStartWaiters();
        $log.log('WebSocket Started: ' + self.connection.id);
    });
}

var isStarted = false;
var waitForSignalRToHaveStartedQueue = [];
function waitForSignalRToHaveStarted() {
    if (isStarted) {
        // Return an empty promise that will resolve immideately
        return $q.when();
    }
    // Create and store a new promise that will be resolved later
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    waitForSignalRToHaveStartedQueue.push(deferred);
    return deferred.promise;
}
function notifyStartWaiters() {
    isStarted = true;
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/25202605/23118
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
    var initialPromise = $q.when();
    waitForSignalRToHaveStartedQueue.reduce(function (prev, data) {
        return prev.then(function () {
            return data.resolve();
        });
    }, initialPromise).then(function () {
        waitForSignalRToHaveStartedQueue = [];
    });
}
```

and this works. But it does not feel quite right and now that I ought to create a correspondingly waitForLoginToBeSuccessful for the other API calls I really do not want to end up with lots of duplicate code by copying and modifying waitForSignalRToHaveStarted and notifyStartWaiters.

So in what other ways can this be handled?

Comment: If the function is called before the SignalR connection is ready - would you like to start it or would you like it to wait for someone else to start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this does not feel quite right. You do not have to implement your own event emitters for completion events - promises already do this for you. Now, depending on the behavior you *might* be able to avoid a deferred altogether.

#### If you want operations to init SignalR if it's not already initialized:

```
var p = null;
function readyConnection(){
    if(p) return p; // already started connection
    return p = self.connection.start(); // start connection and init
}

function init(){
    readyConnection().then(function(){ console.log("..."); });
}

function waitForSignalRToHaveStarted(){
    return readyConnection(); // just ready the connection    
}
```

#### If you want it to wait for `init` to be explicitly called first:

This is trickier, you have to use *a* deferred but can avoid re-implementing the event emitter logic:

```
var d = $q.defer();

// we have no choice since `connection.start` doesn't offer this functionality
// so we resolve the deferred. This style of programming is very uncommon
// the first approach is simpler.
function init(){ 
    self.connection.start().then(function(c){ d.resolve(c); });
}

function waitForSignalRToHaveStarted(){
    return d.promise; // we just return the promise, you chain to it already
}
```

On a side note - your logic in your implementation of `waitForSi...` is very close to what a (naive) promise implementation does inside `.then`. I recommend reading [this good write](http://modernjavascript.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/promisesa-understanding-by-doing.html) about it.

Comment: Yes, I do want the second variant where init is called explicitly. This was significantly less code than I started with :)